# MBXMapKit MBXOfflineMapDownloader size of download

Tags: ios, mapbox

I have an iOS 7/8 app that uses MBXMapKit for downloading and saving maps for offline use.  Wondering if I can determine the size of an offline map download at a certain zoom level (UI has a slider to adjust zoom level) before it's downloaded.

I'd like to give my users a bit of info as to the size of the download (# of tiles and size in Kb or Mb) as they adjust the slider (zoom level) before they download the map tiles.

My only thought:

Grab the slider value, start a download, upon Notification from the  offlineMapDownloader:offlineMapDownloader totalFilesExpectedToWrite: delegate, suspend/cancel the download, display the number of tiles and somehow calculate the amount of space the download will occupy on the device...  Once user is satisfied, they hit the download and everyone is happy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an in-progress feature for determining total files *before* actually kicking off the download:

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/pull/137

But otherwise, yes, that sounds decent.

As far as calculating the space, tile sizes will vary, but you could run some sample use cases of your app and get some average tile sizes as a way to ballpark.